# How can I manage local useraccounts on windows server 2008 r2 with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I should create, activate and deactivate local user accounts on windows server 2008 r2 with powershell. I already do it with active directory, but I don't find the commands for local accounts. Can anyone help me?
Best regards.

Karl

I'm sorry if I were not as accurate as I should be. I have to do it for the local user account on a member server, not on domain-controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Active Directory, it removes any local accounts.  This is intended.

This question would be better suited for https://serverfault.com/

```
function create-account ([string]$accountName, [string]$accountDescription) {
$hostname = hostname
$comp = [adsi]"WinNT://$hostname"
$user = $comp.Create("User", $accountName)
$user.SetPassword("change,password.10")
$user.SetInfo()
$user.description = $accountDescription
$user.SetInfo()
$User.UserFlags[0] = $User.UserFlags[0] -bor 0×10000 #ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD flag is 0×10000
$user.SetInfo()

$objOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$hostname/Administrators,group"
$objOU.add("WinNT://$hostname/$accountName")

$objOU = [ADSI]"WinNT://$hostname/Remote Desktop Users,group"
$objOU.add("WinNT://$hostname/$accountName")
}

create-account "testuser2" "Some Description"
```

Save thats as .ps1, edit info to suit and then run it.

http://www.jrdata.se/2012/10/31/add-local-users-with-powershell/

Comment: I don't think OP is talking about Domain Controllers, but rather local accounts on member computers

Comment: I was unsure, but nothing was mentioned about local machines so I went this way, if the OP edits the question or adds more detail I'll change this answer.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I decided to add your suggestion 'just incase'